# What is the best way to write simple python script that runs on both Unix and Windows

Tags: python, windows, github

I have written a basic internet speed check app in Python (3).  Initially I wrote it to be run on my Windows machine via task scheduler.  Then I copied it across to my Pi (running Raspian) and editted it to work via Cron.  I want to enhance the code but still be able to run it under either Windows or Unix.  I also want to start using github.  So is the best way to maintain 2 separate apps, one app but fork or branch 2 versions in github or do a variation on the them of if os = win then xxxx else if os = unix then...
Hope that makes sense. Thanks.

I currently have 2 separate code bases which are very similar but have differences (such as references to directories / files etc;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same project, of course. Extract the common code (and do your best to make as much code as you can to be common) into base class(es), in `main` decide which platform to call (`import platform; platform.system().lower()` will give you simple "linux" and "windows" values) and then create your instances from that specific class. Something like the following:

```
# myapp/base.py

class BaseApp(object):

# myapp/windows/app.py and myapp/linux/app.py

class App(BaseApp):
```

Comment: Great.  Thanks for the quick answer and the code example.

Comment: Sorry one thing - in the main - if it's UNIX I need to add the shebang at the very beginning - but as it needs to be first I would have to do it before I work out if it's UNIX or Windows.

Comment: Shebang won't interfere with execution in Windows, just add it there if you want.